# How to make no flash 4 bit ADC converter

Tags: adc

I'm trying to make 4 bit ADC converter, but all I can find is a 4 bit flash ADC converter like on the picture below[image]

but I need no flash

Comment: Obviously, you'll have to provide a lot more information than that about what you DO need. What sort of implementation technology is available to you? What kind of performance do you require? Are there any other constraints peculiar to your application? Probably the simplest converter (in some ways) is an R-2R DAC and an analog comparator, connected to a small microcontroller running a successive approximation algorithm.

Comment: Dave, thanks for that clarification, I'm just trying to understand overall technology of building 4 bit adc using proteus simulations, so I don't have any specific requirements

Comment: Are you aware that "flash" in the term "flash ADC" is completely unrelated to the "flash" in "flash memory"? Because it doesn't really make sense to say "no flash" unless you think a flash ADC involves flash memory somehow (it doesn't). Flash ADCs are called that because they're extremely fast--they do the conversion "in a flash".

Comment: Hearth, flash ADC being a little more complicated than no flash, I do not need that for my research, just plain 4 bit ADC

Comment: Flash ADCs are actually simpler than "plain" SAR or delta-sigma ADCs. You simply won't find a 4 bit SAR ADC. But there's nothing stopping you using an 8 or 12 bit ADC and ignoring its LSBs.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it really helped me and that's what I did, just used 8 bit ADC's lower 4 outputs from D4 to D7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a 8 bit AD-converter. You can use either the output bits D0...D3 or D4....D7 or a 4 bit chunk in the middle depending on the scaling and reference voltage. That's, of course, useless if you need the speed which is available only for 4 bit, but not for 8 bit ADCs.